# Portal animation plays in viewport, but not in game (UPBGE)

Tags: modeling, shaders, game-engine, effects, shader-nodes

I created an animated portal which waves around when played, but for some reason it is completely stationary during gameplay. I linked the object and animation via logic bricks but it still does not work after starting the game. Is there any solution you could recommend? Thanks.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the action here:

[image]

to Shader Nodetreeaction ...and it works.

[image]

Comment: Wow it was so simple. Thank you for your answer sir!

Comment: If my answer helped you, please click on the checkmark left of my answer. Thank you. Glad I could help.

Comment: Hello Chris, out of curiosity, how would you go about adding a rotation to this? I tried editing the first keyframe to 0 and last one to 360 which works for the viewport but not the game. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Emre, to add a rotation, just add another keyframe for the rotation value and connect that action to your "and" condition. blend file: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=aSsajVKg" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/aSsajVKg/) , but please open a new question if you have further questions. Thanks.

Comment: ok thanks again